# Prove a contractive function's property using the extreme values theorem

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

I need to prove, using the extreme values theorem, that the image of a contractive function's interval is smaller than the interval. I have no idea how the theorem fits in, hints would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

The idea is simple :

Let $I = ]a,b[$, $f(x_n)$ be a sequence of $I$ that converge to the sup of f on I, and $f(y_n)$ a sequence that converge to the inf of f on I.

Then for all n, $$|f(x_n)-f(y_n)| < \lambda |x_n - y_n|<\lambda (b-a)$$

This imply, when you take the limit, that

$$|\sup_I f- \inf_I f| \leq\lambda (b-a) < b-a$$